# Explanation that the prior predictive (marginal) distribution follows from prior and sampling distributions

Tags: bayesian, prediction, prior, marginal-distribution, conditioning

While I have a vague intuition that this makes sense, I am interested in the formal demonstration that the *prior predictive distribution* in Bayesian inference is equal to the integral over $\theta$ of the product of the prior distribution $p(\theta)$ and the sampling distribution $p(y|\theta)$, such that:

$$p(y) = \int_{\theta} p(\theta) p(y|\theta)\text{d}\theta.$$

Could one say that the integral makes the distribution unconditional (i.e. it *removes* the conditionality) by integrating over all possible parameters?

If so, is there a more formal explanation?

Comment: This is not a proof but a definition. This is what we call the _prior_ predictive (or the marginal), as opposed to the _posterior_ predictive$$p(y|y_0)=\int p(\theta|y_0)p(y|\theta)\text{d}\theta,$$where $y_0$ is the observation.

Comment: Another way of explaining why "predictive": if you want to predict the behaviour of anything related with the random variable associated with $p(y|\theta)$, you need to generate first a value of $\theta$ from the prior $p(\theta)$ before you can generate a realisation $y$ from $p(y|\theta)$.

Answer (score 6):

The equation follows from the definition of [marginal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_distribution):

$$
p(y) = \int_\theta{p(y, \theta)}
$$

And, from factoring the joint probability of data and parameters into conditional probabilities, like so: $$p(y, \theta) = p(y|\theta)p(\theta)$$

(If this is confusing, divide both sides by $p(\theta)$ to get the familiar definition of conditional probability.)

More plainly, and as referenced in comments, the prior predictive distribution is the Bayesian term *defined as* the marginal distribution of the data over the prior: It denotes an interpretation of a particular marginal distribution.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it removes the conditionality. Prior Predictive is for predictive a new value BEFORE the sample has been gathered. The only information we have at this stage is our belief about the Prior, $p(\theta$) and sampling distribution i.e. $p(y_{new}|\theta)$.

After the sample has been gathered, we have new information i.e. the likelihood. Hence, now we can predict based on Posterior Predictive Distribution $p(y_{new}|y_{data})$.